# Why Python module execute only first time codes which are outside function/class code

Tags: python-3.x, import, module

file words.py

```
def print_word():
    print("Hello Words")

print(__name__)
```

When I run above code from console :

```
(base) C:\Users\Desktop\Python>python words.py
__main__

(base) C:\Users\Desktop\Python>python words.py
__main__

(base) C:\Users\Desktop\Python>python words.py
__main__

(base) C:\Users\Desktop\Python>python
Python 3.7.3 (default, Apr 24 2019, 15:29:51) [MSC v.1915 64 bit (AMD64)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from words import *
words
>>> from words import *
>>>
```

Why during import it execute print only once but while running python words.py it execute print as many time as we execute ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you import a module, Python creates a module instance of that module.

After the first import, the interpreter already has an instance of that module therefore it doesn't execute anything

Python's import documentation: [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html)

> When a module is first imported, Python searches for the module and if found, it creates a module object, initializing it.

You can read more about the loading process of a module [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#loading) :

> - If there is an existing module object with the given name in sys.modules, import will have already returned it.
> - The module will exist in sys.modules before the loader executes the module code. This is crucial because the module code may (directly or indirectly) import itself; adding it to sys.modules beforehand prevents unbounded recursion in the worst case and multiple loading in the best.