# Cleaner way to access config(config.yaml) inside APIRouter - FastAPI

Tags: python, import, fastapi

Getting error,

> ImportError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package

if I tried like this,

```
from ..main import config
```

Is there any better way to access configurations across all routers?

**Folder structure:**

```
project_root/
    ├── api/
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── health.py
    │   └── endpoint1.py   # how to access `config` here?
    ├── config/
    │   └── config.yaml
    ├── .env
    ├── main.py            # loads config.yaml into `config` variable
    └── requirements.txt
```

**Code:**

**main.py**

```
import uvicorn
import yaml
from fastapi import FastAPI

from api import api_router


def load_config():
    with open("config/config.yaml", "r", encoding="utf-8") as f:
        return yaml.safe_load(f)


config = load_config()

app = FastAPI()

app.include_router(api_router)  # How to pass the config to the router?

if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run(app, host="0.0.0.0", port=8000)
```

**api/__init__.py**

```
from fastapi import APIRouter

from . import health, endpoint1

api_router = APIRouter()
api_router.include_router(health.router, tags=["health"], prefix="/health")
api_router.include_router(endpoint1.router, tags=["endpoint1"], prefix="/endpoint1")
```

**api/endpoint1.py**

```
from fastapi import APIRouter

from ..main import config # ImportError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package

router = APIRouter()


@router.get("/path/")
def func(request):
    # access config variable
    config['some_key']
```

Running the code from `project_root` like `python main.py`

Comment: make a custom router based on api_router and add it in app.route.route_class

Comment: @sahasrara62 Can you please share the code to do that?

Comment: Try changing your relative import (`from ..main import`) to an absolute one (`from main import`). That should work since `main.py` is in the project root.

Comment: @M.O. Again import error with different message `ImportError: cannot import name 'api_router' from partially initialized module 'api' (most likely due to a circular import )`

Comment: Ah, classic python. Notice the import chain `main.py -> api/__init__.py -> api/endpoint1.py -> main.py`. Therefore, when `main` is imported in `endpoint1`, `app` has not been created yet.

Comment: There are various ways around this, but when it comes to config, which is used throughout more or less every file, it’s usually best to put it in its own file. So create a `config.py` next to `main.py`, and move the `load_config` function and `config = load_config()` there. Then `from config import config` in both `main.py` and `endpoint1.py`.

Comment: @M.O. But, it will run `load_config` every time I import in `main.py` and `endpoint1.py`. How to make sure it load only once, and utilize it in all files?

Comment: No, python will only run the code in a module the first time you import it. As long as you put the line `config = load_config()` in `config.py`, it will only be run once.

Comment: @M.O. Yes, it's not running `load_config` every time I import it, but what is the reason for *python will only run the code in a module the first time you import it.*?

Comment: I found this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59334303/why-python-module-execute-only-first-time-codes-which-are-outside-function-class) for why *python will only run the code in a module the first time you import it.*